# Robotframework: problem understanding test suite concept

Tags: robotframework

Dokumentation about Robotframework says:

> "Robot Framework test cases are created in test case files, which can
> be organized into directories. These files and directories create a
> hierarchical test suite structure"
> ...

> A test suite created from a directory can have similar settings as a
> suite created from a test case file.
> ...

> The test suite name is constructed from the file or directory name.

But how does it works?

I have big robot tests files and I want to split hundreds of test cases into groups/files to get an oversight. In my understanding, the structure of the texts can be hierarchical as the TestSuite structure and in the directories resides the test cases:

For example, following directory structure:

```
tests/test1/test.robot
     /test2/test.robot
     /test3/test.robot
```

But how does the TestSuite file looks like?
There is no example for the TestSuite file and when I instruct robot framework with:

```
robot --suite ./tests
```

it gives the error

```
[ ERROR ] Suite 'Test1 & Test2 & Test3' contains no tests in suite 'tests/test.resource
```

But how could this be?
In the documentation it is not mentioned that the tests in a test suite are defined in a resource file.

Where are they defined and what is the syntax for a test Suite?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use roborframework suites:

I created a directory named "suite" and in that directory placed the test directory with the different robot files:

```
/home/suite/tests/test1.robot
                 /test2.robot
                 /test3.robot
```

then, in home:

robot suite/tests/

It then traverses the "tests" directory for the robot files

[image: robot suite log File]

under the "suite" directory could be created more test directory for new suites